# Within Next.js, Is it dangerous for users to be able to land on API routes?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a general question regarding API routes within Next.js - Is it bad practice or dangerous for a user to be able to land exclusively on an api route? For instance I have a unique situation where a user needs to be redirected on top of an api route (through their browser) for a library to work (`/api/login`) and unfortunately this may be the only option. Is there anything I should be worried about or take as a precautionary measure before putting this into production? Thanks in advance

Comment: Certainly isn't good practice, but I don't see why it would be dangerous.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Going to just use the api routes directly as I stated above and see what happens. Also not to be creepy but I checked out your github from your profile and saw you went to Galvanize, as did I :)

Comment: Haha nice sleuthing! Maybe share more about why you can’t just use a GET request to the api? Sounds like it will respond with a redirect.

Comment: It actually does respond with a redirect but then there are CORS-related issues in the browser since the api is using passport middleware.


`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://...thirdpartyprovider.com' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/api/login/') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I tried using the cors() npm package to add cors headers into the request as well as manually inserting the cors headers before and after the passport middleware but no luck

Comment: These may help 1) https://mherman.org/blog/social-authentication-with-passport-dot-js/ 2) https://github.com/auth0/passport-linkedin-oauth2/issues/43